# UWP : MediaElement MediaEnded Event doesn't fire (Raspberry Pi3)

Tags: uwp, mediaelement, windowsiot

I'm working UWP app porting on Raspberry Pi3 using Windows IOT Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition & Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis (reading the grammar file thru SRGS file). I'm using MediaElement to play the voice thru speaker. Microphone and Speaker are connected to Raspberry Pi.

Challenge: Overlap between the Synthesis & Recognition ie voice from the speaker is recognized back by the program and going in loop. In order to overcome this issue I'm stopping the recognition & starting it once MediaElement.MediaEnded event ends. Unfortunately, this event is not at all firing.

Based on various responses - I have added MediaElement in both

```
    App.xaml
                <Application.Resources> <MediaElement x:Name="mElement" />   
                </Application.Resources>
    MainPage.xaml
        <Grid x:Name="myGrid" Background="{ThemeResource 
        ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <MediaElement x:FieldModifier="Public"  x:Name="mElement" 
        RequestedTheme="Default" MediaEnded="MElement_MediaEnded" 
        CurrentStateChanged="mElement_CurrentStateChanged"/>
        </Grid>

    MainPage.xaml.cs
        private async void MElement_MediaEnded(object sender, 
        Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             Debug.WriteLine("*******Finally reached Mediaended: **********");
                    //await 
    MyRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync(SpeechContinuousRecognitionMode.PauseOnRecognition);         

         }

private void mElement_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
             MediaElement mediaElement = sender as MediaElement;
             Debug.WriteLine("Media Element Current State : " + 
                mediaElement.CurrentState);
          }
```

I have tried multiple ways mentioned in

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/23/using-speech-in-your-uwp-apps-from-talking-to-conversing/#h7bqVM4FJLyogHTl.97

[MediaElement.MediaEnded event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142687/mediaelement-mediaended-event-not-firing)

Unfortunately nothing works!

Comment: What do you play using MediaElement ? How do you do that?

Comment: Hi Rita, I'm playing the text to external speaker attached to the Raspberry Pi using MediaElement

Comment: I don't see `mElement.SetSource()` and `mElement.Play()` related code. Do your mind showing the complete code? Can you listen the text when  playing?